# How can I Read a list from a sharepoint site and make the contents globaly available in my code?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, memory-management, listitem

My code works, when I redundantly put it in objects like button_click or comboBoxApp_SelectedIndexChanged, but when I try to put it in a centralized location i get "The name 'items' does not exist in the current context"

```
       ''' ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://MySharePointSite/ServerMaintenance/");

        List ChangeList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Server Maintenance Windows");
        CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(1505);

        ListItemCollection items = ChangeList.GetItems(query);
        context.Load(items);
        context.ExecuteQuery();'''
```

Comment: What do you mean by centralized location? Which line of code gives the error ?

Comment: 'foreach (ListItem listItem in items) '  in this example the error is "The name 'items' does not exist in the current context"     "Central Location" = globally available..  I am not a programmer.  I am a server admin.  I'm sure there is something simple I just don't know.

Comment: You need to declare `ListItemCollection items` at class level and in above code You need to do `items = ChangeList.GetItems(query);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a static method to return ListItemCollection object and then you can call this function anywhere you want, here is the code snippet for your reference:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ListItemCollection items = GetItems();
        foreach (ListItem item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item["Title"]);
        }


    }
    private static ListItemCollection GetItems()
    {
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://sp/sites/Jerry");

        List ChangeList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestList");
        CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(1505);

        ListItemCollection items = ChangeList.GetItems(query);
        context.Load(items);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        return items;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!